# Qt C++ sorting TableView

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

Last time I was doing "computer service" as a project for studies. I wanted to display actual products in `QTableView`. It went well, it displays values from `SQLite` nicely. I'd like to sort values by clicking on header of the table (sort by column clicked).

Here's my code:

```
QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery * qry = new QSqlQuery();
qry->prepare("Select * from products");
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);
ui->tableView_2->setModel(modal);
ui->tableView_2->setSortingEnabled(true);
ui->tableView_2->show();
```

Could you help me?

Comment: Look at `QSortFilterProxyModel`.

Answer (score 1):

In the snipet above, your sections appear to be sort-able but not clickable.

To add that feature, you can simply call [`QHeaderView::setSectionsClickable()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#setSectionsClickable).

```
QSqlQueryModel * modal = new QSqlQueryModel();
QSqlQuery * qry = new QSqlQuery();
qry->prepare("Select * from products");
qry->exec();
modal->setQuery(*qry);
ui->tableView_2->setModel(modal);
ui->tableView_2->setSortingEnabled(true);
ui->tableView_2->horizontalHeader()->setSectionsClickable(1);
ui->tableView_2->show();
```

This should do the trick, and allow you to simply click on the headers to sort by this column.

Comment: well, nothing happens then. clicking on column headers changes the arrow on a header (for ascending or descending order), but it doesn't sort.  i'll try column click to get sorted column from database and then insert in.

Comment: @Glox I have tried the QTableView part of the code on a different dataset than you and it works fine for me. None of the columns can be sorted, or only some of them ?

Comment: None of the columns can be sorted, just nothing happens when i click the header :/